# Viewing VIDEO_TS in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, video

I had a DVD and I copied it to my Ubuntu computer. It created a VIDEO_TS folder. Now I copied this folder to my new Windows 8 computer. How can I view the video? I don't see any video player to which I can drag that folder.

Comment: Have you tried VLC Player? You can get it for free

Comment: VLC, KM Player can play such files.. instead of dragging.. try to open the folder from the player.

Answer (score 0):

DVDs are funny...you *may* get a video player like VLC to play the individual .VOB files in the folder, but it will be all out of order and not play like a DVD.

Tip: Create an image, not copy the files.

*Disclaimer*: I'm assuming you're doing this on your personal DVDs and not those protected by copyright. Use my advice at your own risk.